# Error when trying to register with Anchoring

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use this application: https://github.com/AnchoringAI/anchoring-ai#installation-guide

However, when I run it on localhost:3000 it asks me to register, but when I enter my data and click register nothing happens. Note terminal appears the following message "See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED)."

Can someone help me?

Being able to create my account on Anchoring